# What's the confidence interval in a population given an inaccurate classifier?

Tags: probability, confidence-interval

I've built a machine learning model on some training data to classify first names as male or female. The accuracy on the training data is **x%**. With the known accuracy, I then predict on a new dataset of **n** samples, and the model predicts that **m** names are male. How can I calculate the confidence interval for the number of male names in the dataset?

E.g. *600 of the names in a dataset of a 1000 names were predicted as male. The true answer, with 95% confidence, lies within the interval 575-625 male names in the dataset*.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! "Bias" has a specific meaning in statistics, and it is not clear that you mean this (I lean toward no). Could you please say exactly what you mean when you use this term?

Comment: Thanks! Let me remove it, I think it just adds confusion

Comment: Are you looking for a confidence interval or a prediction interval? [There is a difference.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/prediction-interval/info) Also, note that [accuracy is problematic as an evaluation measure](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352).

Comment: When you write "I find that $m$ names are male", do you mean that you *predict* that $m$ names are male, or that the new data set actually has $m$ names that are male?

Comment: @StephanKolassa, I think I'm looking for the prediction interval, e.g. "The model predicted 600 of the names were male, with 95% confidence that the true answer lies between 575 and 625"

Comment: @jbowman, predicted, rather than acctual, I'll clarify.

Comment: For less-than-perfect accuracy, I'm not sure you can infer a CI. Suppose your classifier achieves 50% accuracy on a balanced dataset. That might be because it calls everybody male, or because it calls everybody female, or because calls male/female at a 50/50 rate but gets it wrong half the time. On a new balanced dataset of 1000 individuals, these three classifiers will predict m=1000, m=0, or m=500, respectively. If the predicted m value can be literally anything for fixed true m, I struggle to see how it can be informative in such a case.